# Finding zero values and replacing with whitespace/deleting them - Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a tab-delimited columnar .txt file in this format:

```
61200   285700  22000
61600   294000  22300
64400   385200  22500
66100   427600  24000
70700   478500  24400
72300   0       24700
72700   0       24800
78600   0       25200
79900   0       25300
83600   0       26100
84700   0       26300
86900   0       26600
88300   0       27000
91000   0       27200
91900   0       27400
92700   0       27500
```

And I want to find all "0" values (not inclusive of trailing zeroes) and delete these, or replace them with whitespace.

Desired output:

```
61200   285700  22000
61600   294000  22300
64400   385200  22500
66100   427600  24000
70700   478500  24400
72300           24700
72700           24800
78600           25200
79900           25300
83600           26100
84700           26300
86900           26600
88300           27000
91000           27200
91900           27400
92700           27500
```

What is the most efficient method of doing this that can scale? I will be batch processing large numbers of .txt files - and each one is >50Mb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple , use word boundary `\b` before and after to `0`. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character (*vice-versa*).

```
perl -pe 's/\b0\b/ /g' file
```

Add `-i` parameter to do an in-place edit.

```
perl -i -pe 's/\b0\b/ /g' file
```

Comment: The OP says that the numbers are tab separated.. so maybe `\b` is not needed?

Comment: But without `\b` it would match all the zeros.

Comment: I was just thinking that `\b` will also match zeros that are space separated.. but probably it will not matter for the OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
/^(\d+)\t+((0)|(\d+))\t+(\d+)$/gm
```

And use its substitution like this:

```
\1\t\4\t\5
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/oI0mE8/1)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a huge list of files to batch process this is more efficient:

```
perl -pe 's/\t0\t/\t \t/' blah
```

I think because perl is looking for all boundary characters instead of only tabs.

```
marshall@marshall-desktop:~$ ls -lh blah && time perl -pe 's/\b0\b/ /' blah >/dev/null && time perl -pe 's/\t0\t/\t \t/' blah >/dev/null
-rw-r--r-- 1 marshall marshall 53M Aug  9 22:03 blah

real    0m4.077s
user    0m4.048s
sys 0m0.028s

real    0m2.765s
user    0m2.752s
sys 0m0.012s
```